# Nodejs and socket.io, is it pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux

I'm starting to use nodejs and socket.io...

Is it pure javascript or do i have to learn a framework like JQuery or MOntools ?

Thank you!

Comment: Mootools, Jquery are all pure javascript

Answer (score 19):

node.js is pure javascript.

Yes you do need to learn node.js because its your server-side IO library. And no you do not need to learn jQuery or MooTools for server-side development.

Within the node.js community there is a strong emphasis on using 3rd party libraries to achieve what you want. There are currently no frameworks set up for node.

A couple of libraries worth learning are

- [express](http://expressjs.com/) **The Routing, View engine and Controllers (Half of MVC)**

Express is a lightweight MVC library that builds ontop of [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/). This gives you access to a Routing library and a view engine. When used in combination with [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) it will allow you to set up your node.js code to handle incoming routes individually and rendering data from templates. I would also recommend looking at [express-controllers](https://github.com/drudge/express-controllers) which is a great way to handle REST style routing of your urls.

- [now](http://nowjs.com/) **The websocket library**

now is an abstraction on-top of socket.io. It offers a "shared" namespace between client and server. This make RPC trivial. Simply declare a function as a property of now on the server and call it from the client. Now handles all the socket.io communication for you.

- [cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) **The database library**

Cradle is an abstraction that allows you to interact with [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/). If your going to use node I recommend you use a NoSQL database like couch or [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) (Try [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) if your using mongo).

- [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) **General Utility to make life easy**

An awesome utility library that allows you to code in a functional style (think python or ruby). This is highly recommended although most of the features are already part of ES5. Using this on the client to emulate ES5 is also a great advantage

- [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) **The Collections and Models (Other half of MVC)**

Backbone is a lightweight MVC abstraction. This allows you to use more commonly known MVC constructs. For node.js itself I would recommend using [`Backbone.Model`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model) and [`Backbone.Collection`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection) and having express handle the view rendering (but populating the views with data from collections and models). You can also easily overwrite [`Backbone.Sync`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) to interact with your database abstraction of choice which virtually turns Backbone into an ORM. A solid alternative would be [Spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/)

- [futures](https://github.com/coolaj86/futures) **The Flow Control library**

Futures gives you a promises API. This is great for writing manageable readable code. It also stops you from nesting callbacks 5 layers deep. The library itself extensive. It also provides nice abstractions for running asynchronous callbacks in sequence, and for running them in parallel with a callback handler at the end.

**3 Months later**

After having done a few projects, I would still recommend express. However.

I do not recommend

- now. Why? It get's in the way, it leaks. Use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) instead.
- cradle. Why? It has edge case bugs that are a nightmare to debug, use request instead.
- underscore. Why? It's just not needed. ES5 is expressive enough
- backbone/spine. Why? It leaks, it get's in the way. It's just not designed for the server
- futures. Why? It's overkill. you don't need it. Use [after](https://github.com/Raynos/after) instead.
- express-controllers. It's a leaky abstraction, it doesn't work.

Things I would recommend.

- unit tests ([vows-is](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is))
- hot code reloading ([forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever)/[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon))
- scaling architecture ([cluster](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster)/hook.io

Answer (score 5):

jQuery, MooTools and Node.js are all "pure" Javascript if that's what you're asking. However, all of them are also libraries, and you will indeed have to learn their API.

You can find documentation for Node.js [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/).

Comment: jQuery is not a framework. node.js is a framework at a push. (They are libraries). "all of them .. have to learn". There is absolutely no reason to learn both MooTools or jQuery .

Comment: @Raynos, true, I was mimicking the use of `framework` by the questioner here for some reason. Those are indeed libraries, answer updated accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: You still shouldn't be recommending that he learns both jQuery _and_ MooTools (which is just plain silly)

Comment: @Raynos, I'm not suggesting he does so, that would indeed be silly :) I'm just pointing out that the questioner will have to learn an API in addition to the core Javascript language in order to use *any* of them. Is my sentence so weakly constructed it's not obvious? :)